# Eggplant SenseTalk Text OCR function fails after eggplant update

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ocr, eggplant

I have quite a big test suite, around 340 tests and 15 hours of execution time. Almost all tests use to pass first try: usually i had 5 - 10 fails caused by low network speed and (rare cases) eggplant couldn't recognize the word it was searching for even it was completly visible. All failed tests pass on second try.

We had to switch PC e SUT, we took the opportunity to update Eggplant (since our PCs are not connected to internet for security reasons, the last version was 22.0.0). Since the change, more than 80 tests fail due to text recognition. It usually happens when the background is not completly white.

I checked the general settings under text recognition and remote desktop but couldn't solve the problem. We tried to connect to the old SUT and they fail the same way, so the problem must be the new PC in which Eggplant is installed or the new Eggplant version.

I expect the problem could happen because of the way the new PC manages colors and contrast received from remote desktop or some new setting of the new Eggplant version (23.0.1)